# Get list of files whose creation date is greater than some date time

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I have a date `2015/05/28` I want to list all files using order by creation date whose creation date is greater than that using PowerShell. How could I do that?

I googled for it and found `Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files"` but no idea how to compare it with creation date plus order the result by creation date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files" | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt [datetime]"2014/05/28" } | 
    Sort-Object CreationTime | 
    Format-Table Name, CreationTime
```

String is cast to datetime if you specify `[datetime]` before it. You can read about comparison operators by typing `help about_Comparison_Operators` in PowerShell console.

Answer (score 2):

Just filter the output with [Where-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx):

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files" | 
   Where-Object CreationTime -gt ([DateTime]::Parse('2015/05/28'))
```